# Assign constant numpy array value to pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I would like to assign constant numpy array value to pandas dataframe column.

Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3], 'col_2': [4,5,6]})
my_df['new'] = np.array([]) # did not work
my_df['new'] = np.array([])*len(df) # did not work
```

Here is what worked:

```
my_df['new'] = my_df['new'].apply(lambda x: np.array([]))
```

I am curious why it works with simple scalar, but does not work with numpy array. Is there simpler way to assign numpy array value?

Comment: For list-like values it expects to set as column series, so expects equal lengths. `apply` method is like forloop setting for each row.

Comment: You want your data-frame column to contain a bunch of empty `numpy.ndarray` objects?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct. It is like a placeholder, I will be concatenating to it later.

Comment: This would be *incredibly inefficient* from many perspectives. It doesn't sound like you should be using `pandas`/`numpy` at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I have token and POS, gender tags, I need to convert them to vector representation and concatenate vectors. I use pandas to work with raw values and numpy to operate of vectors. numpy array is a result of scikit LabelBinarizer. Is there a shortcut?

Comment: @user1700890 Maybe you should open a seperate question describing what your problem is that you actually trying to solve, what you did so far and give some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "new" column will contains arrays, so it must be a object type column.

The simplest way to initialize it is :

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3], 'col_2': [4,5,6]})
my_df['new']=None
```

You can then fill it as you want. For example :

```
for index,(a,b,_)  in my_df.iterrows():
    my_df.loc[index,'new']=np.arange(a,b)
#     
#    col_1  col_2        new
# 0      1      4  [1, 2, 3]
# 1      2      5  [2, 3, 4]
# 2      3      6  [3, 4, 5]
```